# Screen copying (preferably moving) to another server

Tags: process, gnu-screen

I have a screen on a server machine and want to transfer it to another machine which has the same file system configuration (and possibly same hardware).

Is it possible to transfer the screen to another server machine? I would like to do that because sometimes the machine I am working get crowded by other user processes, resulting in lag on my work. On those cases, I need to manually close the screen, and reopen everything on another server.

Can I make a template copy of the screen process to reopen it on another machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it seems you cannot save it, but you can create a macro to open a screen using the `-c` option.
The idea is to write a script, like:

```
source $HOME/.screenrc
chdir $HOME/place
# Screen 0
screen
stuff "something^M"
# Screen 1
screen
stuff "something^M"
stuff "cd place^M"                                                                                                 
stuff "vim -p `find -type f -not -path \"*/\.*\" -not -path \"*x86*\" \( -name \"*.py\" -o -name \"*.cxx\" -o -name \"*.h\" \)`^M"
stuff "print -n "\\033kScreen1\\033\\134\" "
```

That will do what you usually wants to do when you open a section and then use `screen -c script`